# Is it possible to on-line shrink a EXT4 volume with LVM?

Tags: linux, lvm, hard-drive, ext4

Today I tried this on my machine with OpenSUSE 12.3 (kernel 3.7):

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/system-srv 2G
resize2fs 1.42.6 (21-Sep-2012)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/system-srv is mounted on /srv; on-line resizing required
resize2fs: On-line shrinking not supported
```

`/dev/mapper/system-srv` is an EXT4 volume.

Is it really unsupported or I am missing something?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As the message said, you can only *grow* an ext4 filesystem on-line. If you want to shrink it, you will need to unmount it first.

[According to the ext4 filesystem maintainer](http://sourceforge.net/p/e2fsprogs/discussion/7053/thread/5ad97a88/#9b09/a51f), Ted Ts'o:

> Sorry, on-line shrinking is not supported.

Comment: That's a pity...

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - some moron shooting the messenger? :D

Comment: That was 10 years ago. Has this been implemented yet?

Comment: @duane No. It has not. It is not likely ever to be, either.

Comment: Can you recommend a filesystem that can available to linux?

Answer (score 41):

If the case is remote server without console, you can shrink filesystem using initramfs while rebooting. You need to add resize2fs to initramfs and run it before mounting root.

Debian/Ubuntu example:

/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/resizefs (executable):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

PREREQS=""

prereqs() { echo "$PREREQS"; }

case $1 in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
    ;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

copy_exec /sbin/e2fsck
copy_exec /sbin/resize2fs
    
exit 0
```

/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/resizefs (executable)

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

PREREQS=""

prereqs() { echo "$PREREQS"; }

case "$1" in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
    ;;
esac

# simple device example
/sbin/e2fsck -yf /dev/sda1
/sbin/resize2fs /dev/sda1 5G # see size info below
/sbin/e2fsck -yf /dev/sda1

# complex device example
# activate md-raid containing FS/PV
#/sbin/mdadm -A /dev/md0
# activate VG containing FS
#/sbin/lvm vgchange -ay vg0
# resize
#/sbin/e2fsck -yf /dev/vg0/root # or /dev/md0
#/sbin/resize2fs /dev/vg0/root 5G
#/sbin/e2fsck -yf /dev/vg0/root
```

Now run `update-initramfs -u -k kernel-name` to update initramfs for the kernel `kernel-name` which is set as default in your bootloader (grub). In case of boot failure - you can boot with another unmodified healthy kernel/initramfs. Or you can use `all` to update all kernels, but then you have no way back.

Check that you do not have any tools in your system that grow filesystem automatically (e.g. cloud-init - comment `resizefs` in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`).

Reboot. Check filesystem size. Remove initramfs scripts and run `update-intiramfs -u -k kernel-name` again.

Now you can shrink underlying device with `parted resizepart` / `mdadm --grow --size=` / `lvresize -L`. The size of the device should be bigger then the size of filesystem from the scripts. The simplest way to make no mistakes: if planned device size - 6G. set fs size in the script to 5G. after fs is resized - resize device to 6G, then grow fs to maximum online with `resize2fs /dev/sda1`. Now your fs fits perfectly in your device.

For dracut (Fedora,CentOS) use the same logic (/usr/lib/dracut/modules.d).

This is very usefull for crypting or moving rootfs, with no free space available for the new partition.

Comment: This works like a charm. Note that you need to run update-initramfs with the -u option.

Comment: Cool. In my case I also needed to `update-grub`.

Comment: This totally works, but I didn't think so at first because my hosting provider had stuck an /etc/rc.local entry in that resizes / to maximum size on every boot! Presumably they have a stock image that gets autoexpanded per host.  Banished and all is well.

Comment: Shouldn't the `/sbin/resize2fs` be run with `/dev/lg/lv_root` parameter in case of LVM? My logical volume `/dev/lg/lv_root` consist of two physical partitions `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` therefore I don't think I should be shrinking sdaX directly.

Comment: By 'run update-initramfs', do you mean to run it with the `-u` parameter?

Comment: Added more info from comments/questions

Comment: This is a very helpful answer to a different question. `on-line` == *without rebooting*

Comment: If you write this using a heredoc, don't forget to escape `"\$1"`.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, **you can shrink/move/grow a root partition without any reboots** (nor livecd, nor usbkey): [consult this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227318/11266). It's very well written and easy to follow, although quite long and a little risky.

`resize2fs` **can't shrink online `ext4` partitions**. This limitation, when applied on the root partition may lead you to think you can't avoid rebooting the host to allow shrinking the `root` partition, which might be something you want to avoid. The linked process will allow you to umount the root partition without any reboots. So in this light it is not strictly speaking **online** resizing in regards to the mounted state of the partition, however it remains an online resizing in regards to the network online status or reachability of the host.

Of course, if you only want to grow your ext4 partition, you should stick to the conventional working `resize2fs` solutions.

The general solution I've linked will work on any type of dedicated or VPS solution for instance.

TLDR; this solution implies to `pivot_root` to `tmpfs` so you can `umount` safely your root partition live and fiddle with it. Once done, you'll `pivot_root` back on your new root partition.

This allows pretty much any manipulation on the root file system (move it, change filesystem, changing it's physical device...).

I have personally used this, and it works very well on debian system also, but the guide was initially written in 2007 for redhat, the answer I've linked was updated for CentOS7. It's highly probable that it'll work on your OpenSUSE, although probably with some adaptation.

Comment: This is not 'online' in regards to comparison with 'online grow'.  All services must be down and your root filesystem becomes inaccessible.  Might be worth contrasting this with the livecd or initramfs/rdshell approach in this comment.  I'd hate for people to be confused by this.

Comment: @BrianChrisman This is indeed a gotcha that merited clarification and that I hope I've covered with an edit in my post. Many thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What I like about the referenced solution is that it's 'almost online'.  I did this particular thing by encoding a small script and tools into the dracut command and launched the resultant initramfs from kexec.  If this could somehow keep an ssh session open through the process, that would be best.  I suppose if you build the faked root with sshd and needed files, start another sshd (because you're ssh'd in) on another port, then you can ssh to the other port and verify connectivity before continuing to lobotomize the system.